# Set plot title inside loop

Tags: gnuplot

I am using a gnuplot plot loop to plot data from several plots together:

```
filenames = "my data files"
plot for file in filenames file.".txt" \
title file
```

Right now I'm using `title file` to set the plot title, but I'd like more control over the plot title without resorting to changing my file names. For example, in pseduocode, I'd like:

```
files = [first, second, third, fourth]
titles = [One title, second title, third title, fourth title]
plot for [n=1:4] files[n] titles[n]
```

Note that the titles consist of multiple words, so `words(titles,n)` is not an option. 
Is there another method I can use to give me more flexibility in my titles?

Comment: Could you specify what you mean by "more flexible"? In general, gnuplot supports the `sprintf()` command known from C. But if you have filenames, only, there's not much you can do. But if your filenames contain a series of numbers, you can use something like `plot for [i=1:10] sprintf("file%d.txt", i) title sprintf("Dataset %d",i)`

Comment: @sweber question edited to clarify.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all: good news, the 5.0 version has limited support for quoting text parts for use with `word` and `words`.

With version 5.0RC3, the following works fine:

```
titles='"first title text" "second title text"'
plot x title word(titles, 1), 2*x title word(titles, 2)
```

A second 'hack' would work with the postscript terminal, in case you are using it, and encodes the space inside the title with its octal representation `\040`:

```
set terminal postscript eps enhanced
set output 'spaces.eps'
titles='first\040title\040text second\040title\040text'
plot x title word(titles, 1), 2*x title word(titles, 2)
```

A third version uses a replacement character for the spaces and a shell call to `sed` to insert the spaces after the splitting:

```
titles='first@title@text second@title@text'
sub(s) = system(sprintf("echo \"%s\" | sed 's/@/ /g'", s))
plot x title sub(word(titles, 1)), 2*x title sub(word(titles, 2))
```

You could also setup a function `myword`, which uses `awk` or similar to do the splitting directly. But that would probably require some fiddling with quote characters.

Answer (score 0):

This is indeed possible using `word(string_with_words, index)` :

```
filenames = "my data files"
description= "one two three"

plot for [n=1:4] word(filenames, i) title word(description, i)
```

Comment: I'm familiar with `words`. Unfortunately, I want titles that are more than one word.